# Сортировка вставкой на C++

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c++

Приведите пример сортировки вставкой на C++.

Comment: Ранняя SEO-оптимизация сайта? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот сортировка вектора слиянием на С++.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
inline void swap( T & arg1, T & arg2)
{
    T temp = arg1;
    arg1 = arg2;
    arg2 = temp;
};
template <typename T>
void insertion_sort( std::vector<T> & vArray)
{
    for (int i = 1, j = i; i < vArray.size(); j = ++i)
    {
        while (j > 0 && vArray[j] < vArray[j-1])
        {   
            swap( vArray[j], vArray[j-1]);
            --j;
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: А причем тут слияние, если речь про вставку?